# Craft Commerce WorldPay integration callback failure

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, worldpay

WorldPay looks to be a terrible Payment Gateway, but it's supported by Craft Commerce so we've gone ahead. Right now, I'm having a problem with the callback's failing with a 302 error.

Our site is updating the order following payment, but the user gets stuck on WorldPay's default thank you page.

Has anyone used Craft Commerce with WorldPay yet?

Comment: Going to go ahead and vote to close this since it looks like there was ultimately a workaround for it to be included in the next release of Craft Commerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered your support ticket and given you the fix for worldpay. It will be included in the next release of Craft Commerce.